# My usb 3g data card sometimes switches to 2g but never switches back without plugging it in and out again

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, 3g

Is there a way to automate the redial process once that happens?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [PowerShell] disable+enable all connections

The most elegant method to reset all connections is maybe PowerShell. Save this as .PS1 script and execute it with **admin** rights.

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID LIKE '%'" | %{
   netsh interface set interface "$($_.NetConnectionID)" DISABLED
   Start-Sleep 3
   netsh interface set interface "$($_.NetConnectionID)" ENABLED
 }
```

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ec1879f2-b0d4-4860-8de1-b29a77a02c86/powershell-v2-script-for-disabling-and-enabling-lan-connections-when-there-is-no-network-connection)

---

#### [CMD] disable+enable connection

Save this in a batch and execute it as admin where `<interface_name>` stands for the interface you want to disable and re-enable.

```
netsh interface set interface <interface_name> disabled  
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL
netsh interface set interface <interface_name> enabled
```

- To get the correct interface name, type `netsh interface show interface`
- Wrap the interface name with quotation marks when it contain blanks (otherwise not)
- the ping command just adds a small break of 5 sec to see the effect in *Network and Sharing center*

---

#### [CMD] reconnect mobile connection

(thx @laggingreflex)

```
netsh mbn connect interface=<interface_name> connmode=name name=<profile_name>
```

[image]

Comment: [It doesn't show up either on netsh or rasdial.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fzAE4.png)

Comment: @laggingreflex try to replace first "interface" with "mbn" → `netsh mbn show interface`

Comment: Got to try it out today. Too bad it didn't work :(I had to still manually un/re-plug.) Maybe a way to dis/re-enable the USB driver altogether might do the trick...

Comment: Hmm maybe the second command comes to fast and we need to insert a little pause. Just to test this: Can you split the 2 commands in 2 seperate batch files and execute them one after another?

Comment: The correct command was [`netsh mbn connect interface=<interface_name> connmode=name name=<profile_name>`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8jU4Y.png).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it staying on EDGE is that the driver likes to stay connected to something that works, following "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

As for a fix. It seems that whoever made the driver needs to fix it.