# How to disable and enable network interface while Windows 7 is locked

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, autoit

#### Initial situation

I'm working with multiple workstations on a domain where I'm not allowed to change screensaver or power saving options which is very common nowadays. I often have to switch between PCs and they get locked after 10 idle minutes. Horrible.

Currently I'm using [caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) to prevent screensaver and system lock. But this leads to the problem that my PCs are connected to the network 24/7 all the time. Even at night when I manually have locked all my workstations with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

#### What I want to achieve

My idea is to automate these four tasks with AutoIt or AutoHotKey and trash all 3rd party software

1. Disable a specific network interface once when system is locked and time is between 8 pm and 6 am
2. Re-enable a specific network interface once when system is unlocked
3. Ping a specific IP when system is not locked (this is for keeping a firewall open)
4. Simulate a keypress once every minute so the system won't lock the screen or activate the screensaver

#### What I have tried so far

Since SU isn't about *Give me the code*, I started googling around for a way to determine a [safe way if Windows is locked](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/10543-how-to-determine-whether-the-workstation-is-locked/page-2). It turns out that using `WinExist("A")` isn't reliable enough and I'm stuck.

Second, I know I can simulate a [keypress](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) in a [loop](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) but I don't know which key I should use, that doesn't accidentally opens or executes something.

Comment: _Second, I know I can simulate a keypress in a loop but I don't know which key I should use._ Try emulating ScrollLock. I can't think of any Windows software using it nowadays.

Comment: refer to this answer for scripting your adapter on/off. http://superuser.com/a/526272/179299 credits to @nixda

Comment: What do you mean by "Connected to the network"? Also, why is that a bad thing? Even when your machine doesn't use caffeine, it's still connected to the network when the machine is locked and/or a screensaver is running.

Comment: @MDMoore313 You misunderstood me: Caffeine is not for disabling the network adapter, its just for preventing the screensaver+getting locked. I just want to automatically disable my network adapter while I manually have locked the system

Comment: I understand, just curious what you wanted to accomplish? Are you unable to schedule tasks? If you can sch. tasks, do you have permissions to disable the network adapter manually? If not, then no automated solution will help :-(

Comment: @MDMoore313 I'm able to schedule tasks and to manually disable the adapter. You and Lorenzo think that a scheduled task would be better to automate these 4 tasks? (disable adapter when locked, enable when unlocked, ping when unlocked/adapter enabled, press key when unlocked)

Comment: in fact, i only considered the fact of a scheduled task for times when the QA knows for sure he can disable the adapter.. at the given time. (per example, after work schedule it would disable the adapter, 15 minutes before start of work schedule it would enable it.)

Comment: So, is your question how to disable an adapter with a programmatic process or to determine if windows is locked?

Comment: @Colyn1337 I got my answer on how to detect if windows is locked from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19090497/935614). Building the rest of the script is up to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a powershell script to automate this, using a scheduled task to run the script. You could either have

1)A separate script for each event (logon/logoff, lock/unlock)
2)Pass a single script different parameters based on the event (auto.ps1 /unlock, for example)

Personally I like #2, a little more work upfront but easier to manage. You probably want to look in the event logs to correspond the event you want your scheduled task to be triggered on, I don't believe there is an action in sch. task settings for all 4 of those events, though I could be mistaken.

Finally, make sure your machine can run powershell scripts outright or call powershell.exe with the appropriate parameters:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\autoping.ps1
```

Comment: I think this answer is the way to go. At most it would be two scripts.